# How to download file from particular url?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSURL * url = @"http://192.168.100.161/UploadWhiteB/wh.txt";
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

if (data != nil) {
  NSLog(@"\nis not nil");
  NSString *readdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:(NSData *)data ];
```

I write this code to download a file from given url... but i get an error on line
`NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`

uncaught exception...

so please help me out.

Comment: I don't know Objective-C, but why not catch the exception so you can print it out and find out more about what's going wrong?

Comment: Lol, uncaght expresion is not **that**

Answer (score 4):

Your first line should be

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.100.161/UploadWhiteB/wh.txt"];
```

(`NSURL` is not a string, but can easily be constructed from one.)

I'd expect you to get a compiler warning on your first line--ignoring compiler warnings is bad.  The second line fails because `dataWithContentsOfURL:` expects to be given a pointer to an `NSURL` object and while you're passing it a pointer that you've typed `NSURL*`, `url` is actually pointing to an `NSString` object.

Comment: Does the source of the `NSData` object matter for this method?  [In this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150196/updating-sqlite-database-without-xml) I'm trying to download a .sqlite database into a `NSData` object from a URL, but it doesn't seem to be saving it correctly.  The file is written, but when I try to access it (either through my app or with a 3rd party viewer) it tells me it's not a valid SQLite database.  Does `dataWithContentsOfURL` only work for downloading .txt files or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSString *file = @"http://192.168.100.161/UploadWhiteB/wh.txt";
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file];

    NSLog(@"qqqqq.....%@",fileURL);

    NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

`-[NSString initWithContentsOfURL:]` is deprecated. You should be using `-[NSString  (id)initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]`. In either case, the URL paramter is an `NSURL` instance, not an `NSData` instance. Of course you get an error trying to initialize a string with the wrong type. You can initialize the string with the URL data using `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]`, or just initialize the string directly from the URL.