# Updating sqlite database without XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, updates

My app requires data from a sqlite database.  It will ship with a version of this database, but I need to update it on a regular basis (most likely once a month).  Typically I've been sending updates for other parts of my app as XML through a bunch of webservices I've set up, but this particular database I'm working on now is pretty large (about 20-30 MB), and I'm getting timeout errors when I try to send it that way.

I tried putting the database on my companies server, then downloading it into an `NSData` object.  I then saved that data object to my app's Documents directory.  When I restart my app, I get an error saying "File at path does not appear to be a SQLite database".  Code for this is below.

```
// Download data
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.net/download/myDatabase.sqlite"];
NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(@"%@",fileData); // Writes a bunch of 8 character (hex?) strings

// Delete old database
NSError *error;
NSURL *destination = [app applicationDocumentsDirectory];
destination = [destination URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDatabase"];
destination = [destination URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"];
NSLog(@"destination = %@",destination);
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[destination path] error:&error];

// Save into correct location
[fileData writeToURL:destination atomically:YES];
//[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[destination path] contents:fileData attributes:nil]; // I also tried this, it doesn't work either.
```

Is there a standard procedure for updating a large database that an app will use?  I get the feeling that what I'm trying to do is incorrect and that there is a totally different way to do this, but I can't figure out what.

---

UPDATE:
I've tried a couple things to try to find the problem, but nothing is getting me any closer.  I put the database I'm trying to download from my server onto a USB drive and then onto the mac I'm developing on, and into the Documents folder for my app in the Simulator.  When I run my app by transferring the database this way, it runs without any problem and I can see all my data.

Conversely, I completely removed my app from the simulator and re-ran it, so it would create my database from scratch.  I transferred this newly-made database from my mac onto my server with the USB drive.  Once the file was on my server, I tried to run my "download update" in the code block above, but it still crashes the next time I start my app with the "File at path does not appear to be a SQLite database" error message.

From these tests, I'm confident that the problem is not with the database I'm trying to download.  Something in my "download update" code is corrupting the database, but I still haven't been able to figure out why, nor have I found an acceptable alternate method to get my updates out to my users once my app launches.

---

UPDATE 2:
I've been doing some more searching, and I've learned that a user will need to put in a username and password to access any file on my server.  I now believe that the `NSData` I'm getting back from my code above is actually an authentication challenge, or something related to that, and that's why when I save it with the `NSFileManager` it's not being recognized as a sqlite DB.

The simplest solution I've found to get through the authentication is [here](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/security/a-simple-way-to-download-data-from-a-password-protected-web-page).  When I try to do `NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingMapped error:&error];` (after changing my `url` as suggested in the link, of course), I get an error `NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256`, which is just unknown error.  My `fileData` is `nil` after doing this.  I've noticed this post is quite old, so I don't know if it is still supported.

I also found a different solution to the authentication problem [here](http://iosdevelopmentjournal.com/blog/2013/02/10/an-example-nsurlconnectiondelegate/) using an `NSURLConnection` instead of `dataWithContentsOfURL`.  This is much more recent, but there is some more advanced looking syntax used in that example that I haven't really seen before.  I was able to pretty much copy-paste from the example, and my project will build without errors, but I don't know the proper syntax for using the `fetchURL:withCompletion:failure:` routine from my `UIViewController`.  I tried

```
NSError *error;
NSData *fileData;
ExampleDelegate *download = [[ExampleDelegate alloc] init];
[download fetchURL:url withCompletion:fileData failure:&error];
```

but that gives a build error for sending an incompatible pointer.  I think I can't pass a straight `NSData` and `NSError` as `ExampleDelegateSuccess` and `ExampleDelegateFailure` objects respectively, even though that what they are `typedef`ed from.  I probably have to do something to `fileData` and `error` to convert them, but that `typedef`ing is one of the "advanced looking syntax" I was referring to above, and I don't really know what to do.

It's not included in his example, but I found another `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method called `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973325/nsurlconnection-and-basic-http-authentication) that I think I can just add into the code from the example, and that should solve my authentication issue.  I feel if I just knew how to call `fetchURL` I'd be set.  Does anyone have any advice on what I need to do to get `fileData` and `error` into that call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ultimately ended up using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/README.md) to solve my problem, as suggested by @silver_belt.  I was able to do it without subclassing `AFHTTPClient` though (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444488/using-afnetworking-with-authentication-fails-with-correct-credentials/16445876#16445876), which I posted as a follow up to this question).

In the end, I just had to `#include "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"` in my view controller's .h file, then in the .m I used

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://myUsername:myPassword@www.mysite.net/myfile.sqlite"]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
NSURL *path = [[[app applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamWithURL:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to path: %@",path);
    }
                                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in AFHTTPRequestOperation in clickedButtonAtIndex on FlightInfoController.m");
        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
    }];

[operation start];
```

when I actually wanted to start my download.  Hope this will make it easier for anyone looking to do this in the future!

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem stems from requiring authentication with your server.

I recommend the popular [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library for help with making HTTP calls.  You'd subclass `AFHTTPClient` in order to provide your authentication details, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440059/using-afnetworking-and-http-basic-authentication).

Then in your case, you can use [`AFXMLRequestOperation`](http://afnetworking.github.io/AFNetworking/Classes/AFXMLRequestOperation.html) to download your XML directly.  You may then write it to disk.  Note you will need to read over the [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) to see if the Documents folder is appropriate for your use (which I don't think it is; Caches would probably be better).

Now, the reason your `ExampleDelegate` code (which looks like it came from [here](http://iosdevelopmentjournal.com/blog/2013/02/10/an-example-nsurlconnectiondelegate/)) doesn't work is that `ExampleDelegateSuccess` and `ExampleDelegateFailure` are block types, so you can't pass your `NSData` and `NSError *` pointers.  You need to provide block objects that conform to the signature of the respective types.

For example:

```
ExampleDelegate *download = [[ExampleDelegate alloc] init];
[download fetchURL:url 
          withCompletion:^(NSData *thedata) {
    NSLog(@"Success! Data length: %d", theData.length);

    // Delete old database
    NSError *error;

    // You need to declare 'app' here so you can use it in the line below.
    NSURL *destination = [app applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    destination = [destination URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDatabase"];
    destination = [destination URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"destination = %@",destination);
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[destination path] error:&error];

    // Save into correct location
    BOOL success = [fileData writeToURL:destination atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"File written successfully? %d", success);
} 
          failure:^(NSError *theError){ 
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [theError localizedDescription]}
];
```

The blocks will provide you with the `NSData` and `NSError` instances as required, so you don't need to declare your own.  You can learn more about blocks [here](http://twobitlabs.com/2012/12/objective-c-ios-blocks-cheat-sheet/).

Hope that helps :D

Comment: Great answer. The part about the blocks is just what I was looking for. I can't verify that this works yet, but since the bounty is going to probably expire before I can look at it again, I'll award it to you now.  I might have more questions on it later though.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Definitely be in touch if it doesn't work as expected and I'm happy to work through it with you.

Comment: You definitely put me on the right track.  I ended up doing a complete 180 and moved away from the `ExampleDelegate` code (it was creating other errors later down the line) and used AFNetworking instead.  Since I wasn't looking to do an XML download, I had to do things a little bit differently than you suggested (see my answer).  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

We have large databases that we regularly update.  I'm not sure how "large" is large, but we are updating megabytes of data.  We Update ours as JSON data.  JSON is a little less overhead than XML, and there are lots of readily available libraries (like JSONKit).  Some of our users have poor data connections, and sometimes difficulties ensue.

We have been testing different ways of updating.  One method breaks the data into multiple JSON files.  Each of the files are downloaded separately, and they are then stored separately.  One advantage over using multiple files, is that if one fails, you only need to resend that particular file.

Also, we use multiple threads to process up to 5 requests/downloads at a time.  This requires much more management, but helps us give a better experience to the user.  AFHTTPClient is really good at dealing with this stuff.  I'd hate to not use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've seen a lot about JSON on here, but haven't used it myself yet - I'll take a look at it (and the AFHTTPClient you mentioned).  I considered breaking my database into multiple files, but it is pretty much guaranteed to keep growing, so just how many pieces I should slice it into is a little tough to figure out.  I was hoping to find a different route to take, but this may be the only way.

Comment: I hope it goes well for you.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a completely new / distinct database each time, or is an updated version of the same database?

If the latter, have you considered sending only the changes (either via an explicit list of adds/updates/deletes, or using something like Zumero to automate the updates)?

Comment: It is an updated version, but there will be many records that have changed since the last version.  I believe I remember reading somewhere that updating the individual fields this way would be very computationally expensive, and is generally discouraged, but I may be wrong.  I am not familiar with Zumero, I'll look into that.

Comment: +1: good suggestion: sending only the changes could perhaps mean MBs of download savings versus sending such a large database in its entirety again...

Comment: It does tend to cost more (CPU & filesystem I/O) to update "a bunch" of entries vs. wholesale replacement, BUT "a bunch" can be a pretty large percentage.   You should measure it.    Sending deltas will almost always be less network traffic though, and iOS devices tend to be on slow cellular networks far more then other platforms, so spending more CPU to process a 20 second download is going to feel a lot faster then spending less CPU to process a 30 second download.   Again I would urge some testing (incl. WiFi on/off, LTE on/off, etc.)