# How to hide the header in Html before loading conent in UiwebView iOS5 and above?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a requirement of Hiding a header or div before displaying the html in UiwebView.I tried the injecting js in webViewdidFinishLoad but it has some problem ie first it load and show the html and then removing the header.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to do server side, use javascript to hide the header and then at the bottom of the page have a script that loads to unhide the header.
EGood refrences: [javascript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element) [How can I hide a page contents until all the images are fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028722/how-can-i-hide-a-page-contents-until-all-the-images-are-fully-loaded)

Comment: We want to do it from client side in iOS application.Please provide your input.

Comment: I don't know if it is too late to comment but I think I have a solution for future readers. First, download the HTML ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696559/how-to-download-file-from-particular-url ) then, replace the content between the <header> and </header> strings ( http://www.karelia.com/cocoa_legacy/Foundation_Categories/NSString/General_search_and_.m ).